# CakePHP: redirect via Router::redirect does not preserve params

Tags: cakephp, redirect, url-rewriting, url-routing

I am trying to redirect `/my-old-url/$slug` to `/news/$slug` in CakePHP with the following code:

```
Router::redirect(
    '/my-old-url/*',
    array('controller' => 'news', 'action' => 'view'),
    array('persist' => true)
);
```

Using this code throws an error (may be a bug?)

> Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() [CORE/Cake/Routing/Route/CakeRoute.php, line 381]
>
> ```
> public function persistParams($url, $params) {
>     foreach ($this->options['persist'] as $persistKey) {
> ```

Even trying the following code does not work:

```
Router::redirect(
    '/my-old-url/:slug',
    array('controller' => 'news', 'action' => 'view'),
    array('persist' => array('slug'))
);
```

This code redirects my to `/news/view` without any parameters.

I use the following code to connect the news URLs:

```
Router::connect('/news',
    array('controller' => 'news', 'action' => 'index')
);
Router::connect('/news/:slug',
    array('controller' => 'news', 'action' => 'view'),
    array('pass' => array('slug'))
);
```

What to do?

Comment: Change 'persist' to 'pass'

Comment: @kicaj Either changing `persist` to `pass` in the first code nor in the second one does help. But now, both code variations redirect to `/news/view` without any parameters.

Comment: What cakephp version are you on?

Comment: @user221931 I used to use v2.3.7, but now updated to v2.3.9 (currently the latest version) and my second code example works :)

Comment: Please can you mention what is "my-old-url" here?

Comment: @Er.KT `my-old-url` is a non-existing URL from an older web-application, which I now want to redirect to the new URL. But I figured out that my code above works when updating CakePHP to v2.3.9 (currently the latest version).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There probably was a bug in CakePHP. Upgrading to the latest version (currently v2.3.9) did the trick. The code in my question does work.

Comment: Since there isn't any change between 2.3.7 and 2.3.9 affecting Router::redirect, but there is one in Router::connect where a condition was relaxed, the problem probably was that you hadn't setup the new route properly in the first place.

Comment: @user221931 But I did not change any character in the code. It worked just by upgrading. So I do not think I had a mistake in setting a the route.

Comment: Yes, exactly what I said. You never had the route properly setup and it was failing. CakePhp decided to loose some strict checks in order to make it work even if you didn't setup properly. Hence now it works.

Comment: @user221931 I just edited my question to outline the "news" route setup. Do you think there is a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Have you properly setup your routing for the new url?

```
Router::connect(
    '/news/:slug',
    array('controller' => 'news', 'action' => 'view'),
    array('pass' => array('slug'), 'slug' => '[\w]')
);
```

Then have it do the redirect with

```
Router::redirect(
    '/old-url/:slug',
    array('controller' => 'news', 'action' => 'view'),
    array('persistent' => true, 'pass' => array('slug'))
);
```

I don't believe you need to define slug again (`[\w]`) in the redirect but if it doesn't work then try it (`'slug' => '[\w]'` after `'pass'`).

Obviously you need to test if `/news/test` works as expected with the routing before trying the redirect.

Comment: `/news/test` definitively works, the redirect was the one which did not work. But upgrading CakePHP to the latest version did the trick. My code above works.

Comment: Your second code example containing `Router::redirect` does not work. See my question and comments below. Upgrading did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
Router::connect('/my-old-url/*', array('controller' => 'News','action' => 'view'),array('params' => '[a-zA-Z0-9]+'));
```

Comment: I want to redirect, not to connect a route. My code above works when updating CakePHP to the latest version.